# Как организовать скрытие меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Имеем 2 уровневое меню**

Блок1 и Блок2 на скриншоте http://prntscr.com/kp2tvi независимые, Блок2 находится вне Блока1.

Код примерно такой:

```js
$('.bl-1').hover(function() {
  var childBlock = $('[data-parent="' + $(this).data('children') + '"]');
  $(this).addClass('hover');
  $(childBlock).css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl-1" data-children="vanny">Ванны</div>
<div class="bl-2" data-parent="vanny" style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>Акриловые</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Т.е. по ховеру на .bl-1 ему присваивается класс .hover и меняется свойство display у .bl-2

Не могу придумать, как правильно закрыть эти блоки. Нужно, чтобы они закрывлись в случае если курсор покидает .bl-1 в направлениях право/лево/верх (см. скриншот), либо если курсор покидает .bl-2.

Немного запутано объяснил, но надеюсь, что можно понять суть вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Дичайщий говнокод, но работает.

```js
$('.menu a').bind('mouseenter',function(){
  $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.item.active').removeClass('active');
  
  var dataDropname = $(this).data('dropname');
  var posLeft = $(this).offset().left;
  $('.item[data-drop="'+dataDropname+'"], .menu a[data-dropname="'+dataDropname+'"]').addClass('active');
  $('.item[data-drop="'+dataDropname+'"]').css('left',posLeft);


  $('.item.active').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.menu a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.nav, .drop {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu a:hover, .item a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menu a.active {
  background: #999;
}

.item {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.item.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item a:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" data-dropname="vanny">Ванные</a>
    <a href="#" data-dropname="nevanny">Не ванные</a>
    <a href="#">Тут тоже не ванные</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item" data-drop="vanny">
    <a href="#">Обычные</a>
    <a href="#">Такие</a>
    <a href="#">Сякие</a>
    <a href="#">Никакие</a>
  </div>

  <div class="item" data-drop="nevanny">
    <a href="#">Я же</a>
    <a href="#">Сказал</a>
    <a href="#">Тут</a>
    <a href="#">Не ванные</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вообще, я бы сделал так, на чистом CSS)

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.menu .hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu .menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #000;
}

.menu .item {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu .hover:hover .menu-item {
  background: #999;
}

.menu .hover:hover .item {
  display: block;
}

.menu .item a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

.menu .item a:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu .item a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="hover">
    <a class="menu-item" href="#">Ванные</a>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Обычные</a>
      <a href="#">Такие</a>
      <a href="#">Сякие</a>
      <a href="#">Никакие</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hover">
    <a class="menu-item" href="#">Не ванные</a>
    
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">Я же</a>
      <a href="#">Сказал</a>
      <a href="#">Тут</a>
      <a href="#">Не ванные</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a class="menu-item" href="#">Тут тоже не ванные</a>
</div>
```